# how do I set length and label for variable in R programming

Tags: r

I want to create a new string variable PARAM in a data frame, with length of 100. How do I set length and label for a variable in R programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obscure question, please read guidelines on posting questions... However, here is a tip based on what can be understood:

```
> df <- data.frame(x1 = sample(LETTERS[1:7],10,replace = T), x2 = sample(LETTERS[1:7],10,replace = T), x3 = sample(LETTERS[1:7],10,replace = T))
> df                
   x1 x2 x3
1   E  C  D
2   F  A  G
3   E  G  G
4   G  F  D
5   C  B  A
6   D  A  F
7   D  G  F
8   F  B  D
9   D  E  A
10  E  C  F
# Add a variable "NextVar" with 10 values /same length as df variables
> df$PARAM <- sample(LETTERS[1:7],10,replace = T)
> # OR    (length of new variable must equal length of other df variables
> df$Nextvar2 <- sample(LETTERS[1:7],length(df$x1),replace = T)
> df
   x1 x2 x3   PARAM Nextvar2
1   E  C  D       C        C
2   F  A  G       D        D
3   E  G  G       C        C
4   G  F  D       E        A
5   C  B  A       D        G
6   D  A  F       D        F
7   D  G  F       D        E
8   F  B  D       F        E
9   D  E  A       A        B
10  E  C  F       B        C

#You can also run this with numbers - [Edit]length of var increased to 100 based on comment: 
df2 <- data.frame(x1 = sample(1:7,100,replace = T), x2 = sample(14:19,100,replace = T), x3 = sample(rnorm(5),100,replace = T))
df2
df2$PARAM <- rnorm(100)
df2
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your quick answer. But how do I set the length of Nextvar as $100 instead of $1? and how do I set the label for Nextvar?

Comment: Hi, Ans. updated above -Review resources on managing data-frames on and outside SO.com you could refer to (Eg: https://www.statmethods.net/management/variables.html). The logic is that any new variable that is to be added to an existing dataframe must be of the same length as the other variables as shown in the answer above: `df$Nextvar2 <- sample(LETTERS[1:7],length(df$x1),replace = T)
> df` where `length(df$x1)` is used. If you know the length to be n, just use n.  If the answer above has helped you, it is normal courtesy to **accept the answer** by clicking to the left of the answer above.